# How to simulate low level keyboard/mouse event on osx

Tags: macos, io, event-handling, hid, simulate

I have tried to use Applescript to simulate a keyboard event

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "This is a test"
```

and use Quartz event service

```
CGEventRef e = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL, (CGKeyCode)52, true);
CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, e);
CFRelease(e);
```

However, none of these methods are actually creating low level HID input events (IOHIDSystem "HIDIdleTime" was not reset)

Comment: Did you try using `kCGHIDEventTap` instead of `kCGSessionEventTap`?

Comment: I just tried kCGHIDEventTap but it is not reseting HIDIdleTime. Thanks!